# The segmentation fault is resolved, but cannot figure out why

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

The header file contains:

```
class WorkScene;
class Mesh;

class Director
{
private:
    WorkScene *scene            = nullptr; // owner
    Mesh      *selected_mesh    = nullptr; // borrower
public:
    Director(WorkScene *scene);
    ~Director();

    const Mesh *get_selected_mesh() const;
    Mesh *get_selected_mesh();
};
```

The implementation of the `get_selected_mesh` method is:

```
cvas::p3de::Mesh *cvas::p3de::Director::get_selected_mesh()
{
    return selected_mesh;
}
```

However I receive a segmentation fault at this line:

[image]

---

The segmentation fault error text is:

> The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating
>   system.
>
> Signal name :  SIGSEGV
>
> Signal meaning :  Segmentation fault

---

The segmentation fault **is resolved** when modifying the code like this:

```
cvas::p3de::Mesh *cvas::p3de::Director::get_selected_mesh()
{
    //return selected_mesh;
    return nullptr;
}
```

Well, I can't figure out **why** the segmentation fault is resolved when modifying the code like above, considering the fact that inside the header file, the `selected_mesh` identifier was already declared/initialized as `nullptr`. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Why are you showing the complete screen and not only the error message? Why are you not providing the error message as text. Text is searchable, images are not.

Comment: Your `this` pointer is `nullptr`. Calling member functions on a `nullptr` `this` is undefined behavior. The error is somewhere in the code that you do not show.

Comment: @WernerHenze Right, I'm going provide the error text message.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks a lot. I'm going to study the links you provided. I'm doing the debugging with QtCreator with default settings which in turn the `GDB` is used. I think I need to work on the debugger configurations a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have a `Director*` that is `nullptr` and then you call `get_selected_mesh` on that pointer. This is undefined behavior.

In the case where you just `return nullptr` the compiler does not care and just returns `nullptr`. In the case where you `return selected_mesh` the compiler de facto needs to do a `return this->selected_mesh`. This dereferences the invalid `this` and thus the access violation.

The error is somewhere in the code that you do not show.